# DB Design for table with multiple relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench, erd

I have five tables. They are  as follows:

1. customer_type
2. customer
3. region
4. project
5. car

This is the explanation of the relationships between the tables.
For the first table namely customer_type  the data/row consists a customer type which can be the values of personal, corporate, government, etc.

Depending on which type the customer has there are several rules around what this particular customer can create on the other table. The rules are as follows:

- If the type of customer is personal, the customer cannot have (not allowed to create)a region & project.
- If type of customer is corporate, the customer cannot not have (not allowed to create) region.
- And if type of customer is goverment, the customer can be linked to region, project and car.

One region can consist out of several projects. A particular project can have multiple cars assigned to it.

However like I explained before, if type of customer is personal, the customer does not has region & project. The relationship from customer is directly to car.

If type of customer is corporate, first customer have relationship to project then project has relationship to car. Likewise with government, first relationship is to region, then region has relationship project then project has relationship to car.

```
+Customer Type -> Customer -> Region -> Project -> Car : table relation if customer type government.
+Customer Type -> Customer -> Project -> Car : table relation if customer type corporate.
+Customer Type -> Customer -> Car : table relation if customer type personal.
```

How can solve this, i mean a good table design for this case like what. Sorry for redundant explanation

[image: database design]

Comment: I have edited your question to try and make it more clear. You don’t mention multiplicity anywhere. Can a customer have more than one car? Can a customer have more than one project? Can a project have more than one region etc? Have you tried to design anything?

Comment: Thank you for correcting my question and sorry for my bad english. Yes, a customer can have more than one region, project, or car. A region also can have more than one project, either project. A project can have more than one car (one to many). I have try to design, but i confuse when customer type is personal or corporate. Because they do not have project (for corporate) or region (personal). It cause the relation will getting null sometimes. The design above just can use for customer with type government. It can not solve for corporate or personal. I hope this question more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the cars below. Just create some 1 to many tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Car
(
  CarId int PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)    

CREATE TABLE CustomerCar
(
  CarId int PRIMARY KEY,
  CustomerId int,
  FOREIGN KEY fk1 (CarId) references Car(CarId)
 )

CREATE TABLE ProjectCar
(
  CarId int PRIMARY KEY,
  ProjectId int,
  FOREIGN KEY fk1 (CarId) references Car(CarId)     
 )
```

If you require a constraint where a car cannot be both in CustomerCar and ProjectCar you'll need to search for workarounds for applying Check constraints in MySQL as I do not think it supports them. Customer->Project and Region->Project can be done in the same fashion, as can Customer->Region.

Comment: I am confuse with your design? How about region, how when i want to select region per customer